# Not working import of numbers from text file

Tags: matlab, file-io, import

I have a huge file like this:

> 10,-247,16,0.465829,-11.505979,0.745327,0.000372,-249.809357,0.000596,6.662333,27.868153,0.000000,0.000000;
>   8,-246,16,2.600302,-66.482079,4.309549,0.003487,-249.589752,0.005758,31.830967,38.629253,0.000000,0.000000;
>   11,-247,13,6.514969,-170.550919,10.922515,0.013875,-249.463654,0.023174,60.247765,46.340561,0.000000,0.000000;

I want to select the first number of each row and save this as a vector, and so on with the second number of each row and the third.

My code is this:

```
delimiter = ',';

    ..... sprintf('%s%s_%d.txt',fullDataPath(j,:),soggetti(j,:),s);
                   if exist(filename, 'file') 
                        disp(filename)
                        fid = fopen(filename);
                        fileAllData = importdata(filename, delimiter);
                        fileData = fileAllData.data(:,1:3);
                         x = fileData(:,1);
                         y = fileData(:,2);
                         z = fileData(:,3);
                        fclose(fid);
                        ........
                   else 
                        ..........
                   end
              ...........
```

The error is this:

> Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

I have searched similar error on the web but i don't understand how I can correct my code in this case and why I have this error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is on this line:

```
fileData = fileAllData.data(:,1:3);
```

Dot indexing signifies a struct, but since your file contains only numbers `importdata` does not provide you with a struct with `text` and `data`, but only with `data`, meaning you should just index it normally:

```
fileData = fileAllData(:,1:3);
```

Comment: With this correction there is a new error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions. ( in fileData = fileAllData(:,1:3);)

Comment: @SaraSavio then your data does not have three columns.

Comment: And how I can access to an element of a cell in Matlab? I correct in this way: fileData = fileAllData(:,1); and now fileData is a cell type that have this size: 157673           1. How i can transform a cell in a array of int?

Comment: @SaraSavio one question per post is the policy of SO, that way it also remains readable and searchable for future readers. Thus, please ask a separate question, although I'd suggest searching for this problem in your favourite search engine, as it's very basic.

Comment: I would not have asked if I had not already arrived at this same point but without managing to move forward. (even after searching for days on the web). thanks anyway for the help